# How can I call jenkins plugin (websphere deployer plugin) from command line?

Tags: websphere-8, jenkins-cli

How can I call jenkins plugin (websphere deployer plugin) from command line with parameters like IP/DSN  Connector Type Port user password  and WebSphere Deployment details 
or is there any way to Tiger " deployment on multiple DSN with single jenkins task "?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the WebSphere Deployer Plugin to deploy via a command line. It's not designed for command line use, but rather, it's integrated into Jenkins directly. While it's possible to extract out the implementation to use a command line interface, it's better to use the 'wsadmin' interface provided by IBM.

-WebSphere Deployer Plugin Creator